# Build a Pandas pd.tseries.offsets from timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timedelta

I'd like to build a Pandas `pd.tseries.offsets` from a `datetime.timedelta`

```
In [1]: from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
In [2]: import datetime
In [3]: td = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)


In [4]: to_offset('1H')
Out [4]: <Hour>

In [5]: to_offset(td)
Out [5]: ValueError
```

Any (other) idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This now works for pandas 23.x. I could not find when it was introduced.

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

td = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

to_offset('1H')
>>> <Hour>

to_offset(td)
>>> <Hour>
```

Answer (score 6):

`to_offset` returns a `pd.DateOffset`. So you can directly build this object:

```
>>> td = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
>>> pd.DateOffset(seconds=td.total_seconds())
<DateOffset: kwds={'seconds': 3600.0}>

>>> to_offset(pd.DateOffset(seconds=td.total_seconds()))
<DateOffset: kwds={'seconds': 3600.0}>
```

For a slightly nicer string representation:

```
>>> pd.DateOffset(days=td.days, 
                  hours=td.seconds // 3600, 
                  minutes=(td.seconds // 60) % 60)
<DateOffset: kwds={'hours': 1, 'minutes': 0, 'days': 0}>
```

Comment: Much nicer solution :)

Comment: still as you mentioned the string representation is not so pretty.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9064, I think this could be an easy enhancement

Comment: the string repr is a bit tricky actually, need a reduce offset function

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done using the `to_offset` function directly.

However, what you can do is convert your `datetime.timedelta` into the appropriate string and then pass that in as an argument.

`datetime.timdeltas` have two properties, `td.days` and `td.seconds` which tell you the difference in days and seconds, respectively. This is to say that the `timedelta` corresponding to 2 days and 15 seconds would have `td.days = 2` and `td.seconds = 15`.

The code below will construct a string with the format "XXXDYYYS" and then pass that to `to_offset`. The disadvantage of this is that when you print it, it doesn't look as pretty, that is it won't say `<Hour>`, it'll say `<3600 seconds>`. But I assume you can live with that.

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
import datetime


td = datetime.timedelta(days=4, hours=1, seconds=12)

s = '{td.days}D{td.seconds}S'.format(td=td)
print(s)
# 4D3612S

offset = to_offset(s)
print(offset)
# <349212 * Seconds>
```

And as a nice little function:

```
def td_to_offset(td):
    return to_offset('{td.days}D{td.seconds}S'.format(td=td))
```

Comment: Do you think that no solution without string exists ?